# Maxima and minima points of $f(x) = \sin\left(x - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find maxima and minima points of $f(x)=\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

I want to use the second derivative test so the first derivative is:

$f'(x)=\cos\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ so $0=\cos\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ when $x-\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and that is when $x=\pi+\pi k$

Now the second derivative is $f''(x)=-\sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

$f''(x)=-\sin\left(\pi+\pi k-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

How do I continue from here?

Comment: What are the second derivative values when the first derivative is zero? What does that tell you about $f$ to answer the question.

Comment: @JBKing If the second derivative>0 so it is minima and second derivative<0 it is maxima

Comment: Yes and that is how you continue to the end.

Comment: @JBKing yes but what should I do with the $k$?

Comment: Note which values of $k$ produce minima and which produce maxima as there is a rather simple pattern here if you consider what the basic graph would look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $\sin(x-\pi/2)=-\cos(x)$